# DragonFly Image Not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates, imagemagick, dragonfly-gem

I am currently trying to get image uploading to work on Rails 4. On my development server when I upload a file it only displays on the page as a string of text, and I get the following error in my console:

```
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
[2019-12-10 13:35:01] ERROR Dragonfly::FunctionManager::UnableToHandle: None of the functions registered with #<Dragonfly::Encoder:0x007f92df90d1d8> were able to deal with the method call encode(<Dragonfly::TempObject pathname=#<Pathname:/Users/me/projects/boss/public/system/dragonfly/dev,:jpg). You may need to register one that can.
```

I have tried reinstalling ImageMagick and the delegates but I have observed no difference.

Here is the code for the display and the upload.

```
<%= image_tag @person.photo.jpg.url %>
<%= form_for @person, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the current output:

[image]

Comment: Post a link to the input image? What format is it? The error seems to be a message from Dragonfly.

Comment: The format is JPG. It happens with any JPG image that is given to it.